# Two conflicting rewrites in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I use these 4 lines:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !marker  
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^/?picture.php$ %1? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/?p([0-9]+)$ picture.php?marker&id=$1 [L]
```

to translate `www.example.com/p4444` to `www.example.com/picture.php?id=4444` and I must say it works flawlessly.

Then I have:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ vid.php?vid=$1 [R,NC,L]
```

and that works to translate `www.example.com/7777` to `www.example.com/picture.php?id=7777`.

However, the problem I have is that when I have both of them in use, the 2nd one does not work anymore.

Because this is not a very widely used rewrite, I could not find any solutions to these specific two cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if this works @bombelman

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !marker  
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=([A-Za-z0-9-]+)
RewriteRule ^/?picture.php$ %1? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/?([0-9-]+)$ picture.php?marker&id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Hi, it works as a replacement for the 2nd one. I still need the first 4 lines. I was hoping for "one piece of code" to cover both, however this does work for both rewrites and I thank you for that !

Comment: It was conflicting with other redirects, but I managed to fix that by changing ([A-Za-z0-9-]+) to ([0-9-]+), since only numerals will be used.